# How to define a consecutive subset of digits

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method `colorful?`, which takes a number as argument and returns `true` if the number is colorful, `false` otherwise.
A number is *colorful* if all products of consecutive subsets of its digits are different.

I wrote this:

```
def digits(number)
  digits = []
  number.to_s.split('').each do |digit|
    digits << digit.to_i
  end
end

def product_of_digits_subset(digits)
  products = []
  (1..digits.size).each do |i|
    (0..(digits.size) - i).each do |j|
      digits[j...(j + i)].each do |digit_subset| end
      product = 1
      product = product * digit_subset
      products << product
    end
  end
  products
end

def colorful?(number)
  digits = digits(number)
  products = product_of_digits_subset(digits)
  products == products.uniq
end

colorful?(236)
```

When I try to execute this, I get this error message:

```
17:in `block (2 levels) in product_of_digits_subset': undefined local variable or method `digit_subset' for main:Object (NameError)
```

It looks like I didn't correctly define the consecutive subset of the digits. Any help?

Comment: You're doing `product * digit_subset` outside the block that implements `digit_subset`, hence the error.

Comment: Indent properly.

Comment: The reason for the error would have been quite obvious, I think, if you indented the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reformatting your code I got this:

```
def digits(number)
  digits = []
  number.to_s.split('').each do |digit|
    digits << digit.to_i
  end
end

def product_of_digits_subset(digits)

  products = []
  (1..digits.size).each do |i|
    (0..(digits.size)-i).each do |j|
      digits[j...(j+i)].each do |digit_subset|
      end
      product = 1
      product = product * digit_subset
      products << product

    end
  end
  products

end

def colorful?(number)
  digits = digits(number)
  products = product_of_digits_subset(digits)

  products == products.uniq

end

p colorful?(236)
```

In this code at line 13 you have `each` cycle with empty block body - `digit_subset` is only visible in the scope of this empty block, but you try to reference it later at line 16.

```
  digits[j...(j+i)].each do |digit_subset|
  end
```

In order to catch this type of errors I advise to keep your code formatted with a proper indentation.